# JMeter Installation

Tags: java, jmeter

How can I solve this error when running JMeter:

```
[root@bx1 bin]#./jmeter.sh
```

> java.lang.Throwable: Could not access /opt/apache-jmeter-2.6/lib/ext
>   at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.(NewDriver.java:98)
>
> java.lang.Throwable: Could not access /opt/apache-jmeter-2.6/lib/junit
>   at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.(NewDriver.java:98)
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266) at
>   org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:212)

JMeter home directory was detected as: `/opt/apache-jmeter-2.6`.

Comment: probably user starting jmeter has no permissions to `/opt/apache-jmeter-2.6` directory. Try running as root, but better option is to add needed permissions `sudo chmod -R u+w /opt/apache-jmeter-2.6`

Comment: Check jmeter.log in the same directory and copy error messages to provide more information

Comment: I just came across the same issue. The current JMeter download does not include the lib folder and seems to be a faulty build.

Comment: chmod -R 777 ./ will help

Answer (score 9):

Your JMeter installation may be broken.
You can possibly try the following:

1. try to use a fresh installation of [last available JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi#binaries) instead of your current - if using 2.6 is no requirement in your case;
2. check the integrity of downloaded JMeter archive against [PGP or MD5 signatures](http://www.apache.org/info/verification.html);
3. class `org.apache.jmeter.JMeter` should be in the file `JMETER_HOME/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar`. Check if this is there or not. Check that jar is not broken;
4. check that `$JAVA_HOME` is defined and points to [actual JDK](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#java_versions).

Comment: Hi I already tried the jmeter 2.9, I used the installer which I download. apache-jmeter-2.9.zip, apache-jmeter-2.9_src.tgz, apache-jmeter-2.9_src.zip but I still encounter same problem. Here's what I did I extracted the file on /opt/ then make it executable the apache-jmeter-2.9 by issuing this command chmod 770 -R apache-jmeter-2.9 then copy the ApacheJMeter.jar inside apache-jmeter-2.9/bin and run ./jmeter.sh but I still get or encounter same error. Please kindly let me know the proper procedure or steps on installing the apachejmeter.

Comment: 1. jmeter.sh is very basic JMeter script with no JVM options specified; try also `jmeter` script instead (`./jmeter` or `sh jmeter`); 2. have you checked your JDK installation and version? 3. `then copy the ApacheJMeter.jar inside apache-jmeter-2.9/bin` - no need to copy ApacheJMeter.jar into /bin dir, it's already there in out-of-box installation.

Comment: I had same issue and resolve it by downloading it from different mirror.

Answer (score 4):

There is basically no installation of the Jmeter, you don't execute or the set up file to install it. When you download the zip/gzip from the Apache site unzip, navigate to the `bin` folder and click on the `ApacheJmeter.Jar`. This will launch the Jmeter UI instance. Also make sure you the Java JDK and JRE installed in your system.

Can you please let us know the OS version you are trying to install?

Answer (score 1):

ClassNotFoundException has 2 possible meanings:

1. You don't have a jar with the class defined
2. You have *duplicate* definitions of that class.

Maybe you are stuck with some jar in a folder common to all your java programs? e.g your path, or libraries/java/extensions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JMeter installation is not successful.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
```

The class org.apache.jmeter.JMeter should be in the jar file `<JMETER_HOME>/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar`. Run the below jar command to check if the file exists in the jar.

```
jar -tf <JMETER_HOME>/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar
```

Comment: I got the following error when I run the command you give to me. How can solve or fix that error?


[root@bx1 bin]# jar -tf /opt/apache-jmeter-2.6/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar 


java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:92)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:997)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:242)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1167)
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@bx1 bin]#

Comment: The error shows that your jar might be corrupted. The installation is strait forward and you need not copy any jars in to bin directory. Verify your downloaded file for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound wierd, but I have seen many java program raise such random errors, when run with openjdk which ships by default with CentOS. In such cases, I could run same programs with SUN/Oracle JDK.

You should try that if everything else fail.

You will have to appropriately set JAVA_HOME and PATH, which has newer java in it.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest version of jmeter and run the jar file .

check the below link http://www.thetestingworld.com/category/docs/jmeter/

Comment: Please note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest version of jmeter as it has all the fixes which you could be looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
JAVA_HOME=path JAVA_HOME
```

and modify this line in script jmeter

```
java $JVM_ARGS $JMETER_OPTS -jar "$PRGDIR/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

for this

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JVM_ARGS $JMETER_OPTS -jar "$PRGDIR/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your JDK version. It should always be the latest for jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Below are possbile issues

1. Either Java Path not set properly
2. Your installation of JMeter is not proper
3. Trying to run JMeter from a Invalid directory structure where the
   necessary lib files are not found
4. Finally your Java version compatibility.

Quick fix:

1. Check your Java Installation from cmd promt with java -version which should be 1.7
   or greater
2. If above step works download and unzip/untar JMeter into a new
   directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` occurs if:

1. the jar containing the class definition is not present.
2. there exists some duplicate definition of a class.

The error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
means that the jar file is missing/corrupted, due to which you're getting this error message.
```

You can try these methods:

- Check if this class is present in  /lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar
- Check if this jar file is not broken.
- try to use fresh installation of last available jmeter version
- check integrity of downloaded jmeter archive against PGP or MD5 signatures
- check that $JAVA_HOME is defined and points to JDK 1.6.0 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter Plugin Manager Installation -

For this download the jar file from [THIS LINK][1] and  put inside lib/ext and restart JMeter. You will be able to view JMeter Plugin Manager icon as per below screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

just put your JMeter folder to other directories (like C:\JMeter) rather than system directories like program files, bin, win32....

Answer (score -1):

The only thing needed to run Jmeter is JDK and JRE(which JDK/JRE sersion to be installed depends on the Jmeter version you are installing), which should be installed on your system. And the JRE path should be set in Environment variables. This should be enough to run Jmeter. 
Also once check the compatibility of JDK/JRE version with Jmeter version u r installing.

Answer (score -3):

it seem permision error, try this command line,

> sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/

make sure you have install oracle jdk,check this,

> java -version
>
> java version "1.8.0_45"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build1.8.0_45-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

check java_home

> echo $JAVA_HOME
>
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre

Answer (score -5):

try this

> sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/

Comment: Is this a joke? No, please NO, DO NOT TRY THIS! `chmod -R 777` is usually a bad practice, depending on what follows (`/mydir/uploads/` might be acceptable for example). Here this is a directory at root level used to install software, you should never do that.

Comment: /opt/ is the system folder and this message java.lang.Throwable: Could not access /opt/apache-jmeter-2.6/lib/ext, you should have root or permission to  acess that folder

Comment: To that very specific directory, yes, but not a 777 on `/opt/`!!